# ASP.NET MVC: A PreAuthorize-like event, Good throttle point for concurrent logons?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I want to allow a new login to 'kick' a prior login session by the same account, in ASP.NET MVC.

It seems pretty clear that I'll give each browser a cooking representing the session ID. I'll track the currently active session ID in a server-side cache. If an already-active user attempts to log in, I'll verify the business logic (username, password, has been at least 15 minutes since last activity), and then update the active session ID cached at the server.

**Now my issue is, *a browser is holding an invalid session ID. What is the best point for me to inject a rejection or redirect to sign-in for this scenario?***

I could modify the AuthorizeAttribute, but it seems like there should be a cleaner place to do this that won't require me to search and replace all my Authorize attributes, for example via a Global.asax event, or a controller event (I've already extended Controller in my project).

For example, if PreAuthorize existed, I would write some code there to test the request's cookies for a valid user/session ID pair, and if it didn't exist, I could simply remove the authentication cookie from the request, which would result in a standard unauthorized redirection.

Comment: An SO article referenced http://teknohippy.net/2008/08/21/stopping-aspnet-concurrent-logins/ , which suggested Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute in global.asax. I'm investigating using that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of research, it seems that a custom AuthorizeAttribute would typically be the correct approach. However, in my case, since I already had a custom role provider implemented, it was just a line of code to do it there. This also benefited me because I only wanted session concurrency for a single role. A side effect is that any use of web.config to control access to static files by role is also in-effect for session concurrency.

Comment: I had to turn off cookie role caching too.